# SSRS Data always show on third page

Tags: reporting-services

I'm new on SSRS and I want to create report, standard report.
When I finish assign my data to textbox on Table, why my data show on the next 2 page?

My sample report.

[image: my sample report]

Comment: Not sure why you have the SSIS link?

Comment: the screenshots are small to view so is the data being shown on page 3 the end columns to the right of the report?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the report body + margins does not exceed the page width. When this happens, the blank area to the right of the report which will not fit on page one will 'print' on page two but as this is just white space you don't see anything, then the rest of the report will print on page three.

First try to reduce margins as this is the easiest thin to do, if the problem will occurs then you have to make the body contents narrower.